# I can't read mysql binary log

Tags: mysql, file, binary, logging

When I try to view a binary log file on my Free BSD server (/var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0) with mysqlbinlog using the following command:

I get the error "File is not a binary log file."

$ sudo mysqlbinlog -f ib_logfile0 > ib_0.sql

After that, ib_0.sql contains:

{ `/*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/; 
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/; 
DELIMITER /*!*/; 
ERROR: File is not a binary log file` }

I've verified that it is a binary file and I have read there is a possibility that file is an innodb log file. Anyway, I can't read that file and I don't find any solution. Is there another way to view this file?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify `-f` switch here, because it looks like it is making output file look similar to actual binlog.

```
mysqlbinlog binlog.000001 > filename.txt
```

Following blog post can be of reference for your help:
http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-read-mysql-binary-log-files-binlog-with-mysqlbinlog/